# Why does QGIS Browser 2.12.1 keep freezing/crashing when I try to view a csv data table?

Tags: qgis, csv, browser

I've just downloaded QGIS Lyon 2.12.1.  The desktop application works great but the browser crashes whenever I try to view a csv data table.  I've gotten it to work once out of ten tries.  I click on the csv file and it just starts working...and never stops. The biggest file size I've attempted in 320 MB.  Below you can see what I'm looking at:

Screenshot too:
      [image]
Does it matter how big the files are?  Seems like anything I try over 100 MB just won't work.

Comment: I've been having trouble with CSVs lately too with the latest QGIS and GDAL but haven't had time to dig into it. Can you try and reproduce the problem - that leads to some details that a dev can help with and this might be a potential bug report for either GDAL or QGIS.

Comment: All - me too... Felix - how big is the CSV? rows/columns/ disk space?

Comment: The size of the file normally would have an impact. I tried with QGIS 2.12.2 Browser (no GRASS) for a csv file of 4.21 MB and although it was slightly sluggish going through the attributes, it didn't crash for me. Perhaps give 2.12.2 a try?

Comment: It's on my home computer so I'll check tonight.  It's a pretty big file, 800,000 plus rows with about 20 columns. I'll post some more specifics tonight.

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  Wife, kids, and full time over here.  The biggest csv file I've tried to view in the QGIS browser comes 320 mb.  Is that the problem?